# Bounds of system of closed intervals

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

From Vladimir Zorich Analysis I:

> if $I$ is any system of nested closed intervals, then
>
> $$\sup \{a \in \mathbb{R} \mid [a, b] \in I \} = \alpha \leq \beta =
>  \inf \{b \in \mathbb{R} \mid [a, b] \in I\}$$
>
> and
>
> $$[\alpha, \beta] = \bigcap\limits_{[a, b] \in I}[a, b]$$

By visualizing finite nested intervals on a line, the assertion above seems trivial. However, in order to mathematically show it, Cantor's intersection theorem was the first thing that came to my mind:

$$\exists c \in \mathbb{R}, c \in \bigcap\limits_{[a, b] \in I}[a, b]$$

In other words:

$$\exists c \in \mathbb{R}, a \leq c \leq b, \forall [a, b] \in I$$

Now if $I$ is finite (and by definition closed and bounded), then $\alpha$ and $\beta$ belong to their respective sets as maximum and minimum elements respectively and by Cantor's intersection theorem $\alpha \leq c \leq \beta \Leftrightarrow \alpha \leq \beta$. Let $c \in [\alpha, \beta]$ any point of our interval and $I_k = [a_k, b_k] \in I$ be any interval, then by definition, $a_k \geq \alpha \geq c \geq \beta \geq b_k \Leftrightarrow c \in I_k$, hence all intervals in $I$ contain all points of $[\alpha, \beta]$.

## Question:

What happens when $I$ is infinitely nested?

I know by monotone convergence theorem sets $\{a \in \mathbb{R}\, \mid [a, b] \in I\}$ and $\{b \in \mathbb{R}\ \mid [a, b] \in I\}$ both converge to $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively. However how can I show that it still applies that $\exists c \in \mathbb{R} \alpha \leq c \leq \beta$ ?

Thank you!

Comment: "infinitely nested"? Quid est?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you for the response. I was aware that my implicit terminology would negatively affect the clarity of the question. By "infinitely nested" I imply a system of intervals $I$, which contains $I_k \in I$ such that $\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}, \epsilon > 0, |I_k| < \epsilon$, where $|I_k|$ is the length of the interval. i.e the system of intervals which contains infinitely small interval

Comment: @ShellRox is there not the extra condition that two intervals $I,J$ that both belong to $\mathcal I$ have an empty intersection $I\cap J=\varnothing$? That's what I encountered by searching for the concept. If the answer on this is "no" then my answer is useless.

Comment: @drhab Is that possible by Cantor's intersection theorem? I think all the intervals in the nested interval system $I$ must have a common point $c$. I assume this does not apply for certain cases?

Comment: My answer gives a proof of that **if** we are dealing with a collection of closed intervals such that $I\cap J\neq\varnothing$ for every pair $I,J$ of intervals belonging to that collection. My question in former comment to you is: are we indeed dealing with such a collection? If the answer is "no" then (again) my answer is useless.

Comment: @drhab Yes, my textbook has a proof that every nested sequence of closed intervals has an nonempty intersection. Your answer proves that if $\beta < \alpha$, then there exist two intervals a collection $[a_1, b_1]$ and $[a_0, b_0]$ in $I$ that do not admit the definition of nonempty intersection. I think your answer then is not useless, correct?

Comment: I am not so much concerned with a proof in your textbook but more with the definition that it gives of *system of nested closed intervals*. Have two  elements of such a system always have a non-empty intersection? If so then it can be proved that the intersection of the whole system is not empty. That is done in my answer.

Comment: @drhab Well I was aware that the intersection of whole system had to be non-empty. I knew that $a \leq c \leq b, c \in \mathbb{R}$ held $\forall a \in A, \forall b \in B$, but I wanted to ensure in abstract sense that $a \leq \alpha \leq c \leq \beta \leq b$ also holds in all cases which seems extremely obvious but perplexing. I apologize for implicit question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no $c\in\mathbb R$ exists with $\alpha\leq c\leq\beta$ then we must have $\beta<\alpha$.

Taking $a_0\in A$ close enough to $\alpha$ and $b_1\in B$ close enough to $\beta$ we find $b_1<a_0$.

Then $b_0\in B$ and $a_1\in A$ must exist with $[a_i,b_i]\in I$ for $i=1,2$.

But then $[a_1,b_1]\cap [a_0,b_0]=\varnothing$ and a contradiction is found.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I apologize if this is an ignorant question, but how does the bound inequality $b_1 < a_0$ imply the existence of $b_0$ and $a_1$ with $[a_0, b_0], [a_1, b_1] \in I$? What do $b_0$ and $a_1$ represent?

Comment: The existence of $b_0$ with $b_0\in B$ and $[a_0,b_0]\in I$ is not a consequence of $b_1<a_0$ but of the fact that $a_0\in\{a\in\mathbb R\mid [a,b]\in I\}$. Similarly the existence of $a_1$ with $a_1\in A$ and $[a_1,b_1]\in I$ is not a consequence of $b_1<a_0$ but of the fact that $b_1\in\{b\in\mathbb R\mid [a,b]\in I\}$. After the observation that $b_0$ and $a_1$ exist the inequality $b_1<a_0$ can be extended to $a_1\leq b_1<a_0\leq b_0$, showing that the intervals $[a_1,b_1]$ and $[a_0,b_0]$ are disjoint.

Comment: Observe that $$a_0\in\{a\in\mathbb R\mid [a,b]\in I\}\iff\exists b[[a_0,b]\in I]$$allowing us to conclude that some $b_0$ exists with $[a_0,b_0]\in I$.